# What building(s) should I save in the event of any enemy ubercharge?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

Of these buildings, what building(s) should I save in the event of any enemy ubercharge (Medi Gun/Kritzkrieg/Quick-Fix/Vaccinator)?

1) Sentry Gun Level 1/2/3

2) Dispenser Level 1/2/3

3) Teleporter Entrance/Exit Level 1/2/3

Comment: This is going to depend entirely on the scenario as it happens.  Sometimes, you're going to want to save the Sentry, others the Teleporter, or Dispenser.

Comment: Build a dispenser to keep your medic healthy so he can overheal your pyro and stuff the enemy uber or even counter with his own uber.

Comment: If the enemy tries to use a Kritzkreig against your nest, don't run. Kritz do not do extra damage to buildings to my knowledge. If it is untrue anymore, please for give me.

Comment: @ShadowZorgon This is correct. `Buildings are immune to critical hits and mini-crits` **Source:** [TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/index.php?title=Buildings&oldid=1518359#Overview)

Comment: On the other hand, YOU should take a defensive position if you are rushed by a Kritzkreig, because you personally become much more vulnerable, and not being able to manage your sentry nest can mean the difference between a win and a loss.

Answer (score 6):

As fbueckert states in the comments this will change from situation to situation. I will not go over every situation here, but I will offer you the following advice.

The medic combo has 9 times out of 10 ubered in order to take out your sentry gun. If you pick up the sentry gun you are going to become the main target and you will probably lose everything.

Considering this I would suggest saving the dispenser if you are on defense so you can rebuild everything quickly. Whereas if you are on offense try saving the teleporter if your team has a real long way to go. Never underestimate how useful a teleporter can be.

NOTE: I would like to agree with badp's answer. If you think you can repair through the damage coming your way always do that. Also with the point of tanking damage that the uber would spend elsewhere putting the "team" in the game.

Comment: you might also consider using the wrangler to tank out your sentry if you have help repairing

Comment: @char1es I think your comment is the most correct answer, for the majority of different scenarios!

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of a single situation where you wouldn't want to protect your level 3 sentry. Yes, you and your nest might be doomed, but every second of invincibility spent on your nest is a second of invincibility not  spent on the rest of your team. Even on offence, where your teleporter is more important than your sentry, you want to tank the sentry that's protecting your teleporter.

Stand by your sentry, aim at the enemy pocket, crouch, use the wrangler to multiply your sentry's hit points by six, then wrench it to heal it, then wrangle again, rely on your team to counter the uber with you. Stickies? Shoot rockets at the ground directly below the sentry, pushing them away - possibly onto you. Heavy? Crouch. Kritz soldier? Take cover behind dispenser. etc.

The single worst move you can do is actually pick up a building. An unmanned level three building is typically easy pray of uber combos, and if you really don't care about that sentry - maybe it was level 2 and truly doomed - then the next best thing is to get yourself out of there alive, and get out of there fast -possibly even before the uber arrives. A dead teleporter is a bummer, but a dead teleporter and a dead engineer is worse. Picking up buildings makes you slower and all the more unlikely that the enemy team will give you a chance to survive.

All of this, of course, applies to actual sentries. Mini sentries vs ubers is a no brained; just get the hell out of there for the next eight seconds, then plop down seventy more minis. The uber isn't coming for you, so this should be rather more feasible.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing that should survive an uber is you. Obviously you can get all of your buildings back up a lot faster if you don't have a ~15 second respawn and a run back before you start to rebuild. While dealing with a push, if your team is there to resist it, watching your sentry die from safety is a lot better than you dying along with it.

That said, usually your second priority is the sentry, because that's the lynchpin of the defense, if you've placed it well. Using some combination of wrangling and repairing can usually keep it up.

#### Demoman Uber

Do **not** get near your sentry while the demoman is spamming it. Stay at a safe distance with your wrangler out. With the shields up, the demoman would have to spend pretty much the entire uber shooting stickies in order to take down the gun in one detonation. If he detonates the stickies, run in and give your gun a whack but get back as soon as possible. You can take one sticky, but don't wait for any more.

#### Heavy Uber

Since you don't have to worry about splash damage, you can crouch behind your sentry while wrangling it and repairing it. Once the uber is down, you can kill the heavy and medic with the wrangler.

#### Soldier Uber

Same concern with the splash damage as for a demoman uber, but rocket damage against the sentry is pitiful, and with the wrangler you can probably keep the gun up through the entire uber unless he spends 100% of the uber shooting rockets right at the gun. The biggest concern with a soldier uber is that he will probably go after you. He will shoot your feet, knock you up into the air, and kill you with a second shot. All you can do is run while holding the wrangler in the hopes that the gun survives long enough to kill the solider after the uber is over. If the soldier actually tries to kill your wrangled sentry with the stock rocket launcher, chuckle gently to yourself while waiting for the uber to end.

#### The rest of the team

The other classes can't really put out the necessary damage to bring the gun down. Maybe a spy ubered in spamming your sentry with the sapper could take the gun down, but let's hope the other team respects you a little more.

During coordinated pushes, the spy will decloak from nearby and sap the sentry. That would absolutely mean the end of you *and* your sentry if you tried to unsap it while the other team is spamming you, and crouching behind your gun repairing it leaves you perfectly exposed to get backstabbed. Just stay safe and hope your team can hold them back so you can either get another sentry up or retreat.

Answer (score 0):

Always the teleporter, then dispenser. Sentry last

Comment: I approve.  Teleporters are the main building your team relies on to put pressure on the enemy team.  The sentry can always be rebuilt elsewhere. The teleporter? Takes much more time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running away with the dispenser. While your sentry will be doomed for sure, you will be able to quickly rebuild it with the metal stored in your dispenser. As for your teleporter, you didn't just leave that lying in plain sight, right?

The important thing is, your buildings are all doomed to explode some time or the other. But after the rest of your team drives them back, you can quickly get your sentry back to level three.